# Is there an alternative to the pipe syntax for ranges-v3?

Tags: c++, range

The pipe | syntax in ranges-v3 is great but it required knowing up front all of the view's I'd like to append... Is there an alternative syntax that lets me optionally connect views depending on some condition?

Comment: What would such code hypothetically look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rangesv3 uses the type system to store information about what the operations are.  This makes things very efficient at runtime, as the compiler knows what happens to the data as it passes from one step to another.

To do what you want, you need to *erase* the type information and forget it.

To this end, they have various `any_view`s.  An "`any_input_view<int>`" can store a terminal of a pipe that will output `int`s.

If you then have a transformation `double_values` that, well, doubles values, you can do:

```
any_input_view<int> double_the_view( any_input_view<int> in ) {
  return std::move(in) | double_values;
}
```

note, however, that each such stage has a performance hit compared to the non-type erased version.